# Visual Studio 2013: Shortcut for 'Toggle Comment'

Tags: visual-studio-2013, shortcut, comments

In Visual Studio you can "comment in" or "comment out" selected lines of code with two different shortcuts.

I want a single shortcut, to **toggle** the comment. So I don't have to care about two shortcuts.

In Visual Studio 2010 I solved this by creating a macro that did this for me. 2013 no longer supports macros.

How can I accomplish the same in 2013?
I also have ReSharper if that helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `ReSharper | Edit | Comment with Line Comment` and `ReSharper | Edit | Comment with Block Comment` (related shortcuts are shown near a menu item name and depend on selected keymap scheme). If you select already commented code and hit the shortcut for `Comment with Line Comment` action - it will uncomment the code and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected. Sadly it is not default functionality in VS.

Answer (score 1):

no there is.
select lines and:
Ctrl+E than C to comment
Ctrl+E than U to uncomment

old style
Ctrl+K than Ctrl+C to comment
Ctrl+K than Ctrl+U to uncomment

both will work forever. VS standards.